# Method transform() in Type Lists Not Applicable

Tags: java, guava

I am trying to use a Guava function to remove duplicates from a List. The reasoning for this is that a "duplicate" is based on a comparison between two items in the list, and whether these objects are "duplicate" requires a fair amount of logic.

Here is my attempt at the function:

```
private Function<List<BaseRecord>, List<BaseRecord>> removeDuplicates = 
        new Function<List<BaseRecord>, List<BaseRecord>>() {

    public List<BaseRecord> apply(List<BaseRecord> records) {


        List<BaseRecord> out = Lists.newArrayList();


        PeekingIterator<BaseRecord> i = Iterators.peekingIterator(records.iterator());

        while (i.hasNext()) {
            BaseRecord current = i.next();

            boolean isDuplicate = false;

            if ( i.hasNext() ) {

                BaseRecord next = i.peek();


                // use a ComparisonChain to compare certain fields, removed
                isDuplicate = compareCertainObjects(o1, o2);

            }

            if ( !isDuplicate ) {
                out.add(current);
            }
        }


        return out;
    }

};
```

I then try to call it with Lists.transform(originalRecords, removeDuplicates)

Unfortunately, Eclipse isn't happy:

```
The method transform(List<F>, Function<? super F,? extends T>) in the type Lists is not applicable for the arguments (List<BaseRecord>, Function<List<BaseRecord>,List<BaseRecord>>).
```

BaseRecord is an abstract class, with at least two subtypes. The fields being compared are all parent of BaseRecord, not the child classes.

Did I just make a dumb mistake?

Answer (score 5):

The reason is - 
you're using Function from package
java.blah-blah.function.Function.
But Guava wants here

```
import com.google.common.base.Function;
```

Answer (score 2):

`Lists.transform` is not intended for transforming the `List`, but its *elements*. You could try wrapping `originalRecords` into another List, but that doesn't seem like a "pretty" solution.

However, maybe you can refactor your `Function` into a `Predicate` and use `Collections2.filter`

Comment: Unfortunately, part of the checking for duplicates requires getting the next element, then comparing the two items. Predicate only takes a single argument and returns a boolean.

Comment: You can initialize the Predicate with the List as its member, so it will have access.

Comment: It doesn't look like using a `Predicate` will be really necessary, either.  I don't see anything Guava can do here to improve the direct approach.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like Guava is really necessary here at all, except maybe for `newArrayList()`:

```
  List<BaseRecord> dedupe(List<BaseRecord> records) {
    List<BaseRecord> out = Lists.newArrayList();
    for (BaseRecord current : records) {
       boolean isDuplicate = false;
       for (BaseRecord other : out) {
         if (compareCertainObjects(current, other)) {
           isDuplicate = true;
           break;
         }
       }
       if (!isDuplicate) {
         out.add(current);
       }
     }
     return out;
  }
```

...and then just call `dedupe(records)`, without going through a `Function`.

Comment: True, but the removal of duplicates was only the first step in several steps that would filter the list. I was hoping to clean up the existing code by simply having a function containing several Lists.transform() calls.

Comment: It sounds like you should just have a function containing several perfectly normal function calls.  You haven't yet shown any examples where `Lists.transform` would actually help.

Comment: `Lists.transform` takes a `List<T1>`, and a `Function<T1, T2>`, and returns a `List<T2>`.  None of what you've described looks like that.